# how to setup appium for iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, appium

I was trying to setup appium for iOS automated testing, but I keep getting this error while running ./reset.sh

does anyone know how to fix the issue?

```
Running "setConfigVer:ios" (setConfigVer) task
Config file exists, updating it
{"git-sha":"1c004673dcc4a2af7357aff4be72a2da7f9f86bc","ios":{"version":"1.2.3"}}
Done, without errors.
* Installing ios-sim-locale
cp: build/ios-sim-locale: Permission denied
---- FAILURE: reset.sh exited with status 1 ----
```

Comment: Did you install appium from source?

Comment: Yes. `reset.sh` is only available if you're running from source.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a "Permission denied" error,

try: `sudo ./reset.sh --ios` ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, for some reason the build folder inside my repo, had the wrong permissions. I simply removed it (it's an empty folder) and `mkdir` a new one with the same name.